# Out of place transformations on Python list?

Tags: python, list

I need to perform a lot of transformations (swap elements, remove elements) on a list and be able to retract those changes in an efficient way. Ideally, I'd like to perform operations that don't work on the original list (in-place), but return a view on the source list together with the transformation (and somehow hide this implementation detail behind a list interface). Since the lists are big and I only anticipate a few transformations, my intuition is that [out of place transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) would limit the amount of data being copied.

Is there any Python built-in type for this or does anyone have an idea of how to implement this efficiently?

**Update**

Some code to illustrate the idea:

```
class Transformation(object):
    pass


class SwapTransformation(Transformation):
    def __init__(self, index1, index2):
        self.index1 = index1
        self.index2 = index2


class RemoveTransformation(Transformation):
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index


class MyList(object): # or MyList(list)?
    def __init__(self, src, transformation=None):
        self._src = src
        self._transformation = transformation

    def swap(self, index1, index2):
        return MyList(self, SwapTransformation(index1, index2))

    # Need to overwrite all of these to honour the particular transformation.
    # All the below methods need to be applied to self._src
    #extend
    #append
    #remove
    #pop
    #__delitem__
    #__setitem__
    #__iadd__
    #__imul__
    #__setslice__
    #__delslice__
```

---

Usage

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
m1 = MyList(l)

print m1
[1, 2, 3, 4]

m2 = m1.remove(3)
print m2
[1, 2, 4]

print m1
[1, 2, 3, 4]

m3 = m2.swap(0, 1)
print m3
[2, 1, 4]
print m2
[1, 2, 4]

# Still possible to retract the changes by accessing `m1` or `m2`. 
# Original list is shared between them to save memory and costly 
# copying operations; none of these operations (swap/remove) 
# required a copy of `l`
```

Comment: I'd suggest to define an object which stores the original list, the list of applied transofrmations (so that you can go back) and the final result...

Comment: @Don I understand that you suggest to make a copy of the list before applying a transformation. That's what I'm currently doing. However, since the list is relatively big, making a copy incurs a sizeable performance hit (leave alone the amount of memory required to create a savepoint before each transformation). I'm looking for a bit of a smarter solution.

Comment: I would not make a copy of the list at all, particularly not if it's big. Instead, give your `Transformation` classes methods like `apply` and `undo`; then you can store those transformations on a stack and undo them later. That's how most editors do it.

Comment: You're right. The final result list was just to avoid reapplying transformations and you can skip it as tobias_k suggests. But, if you want store a link to the original list instead of a copy, be sure that the original list won't change (you could store a checksum to test for integrity)

Comment: @Don: The original list won't be changed and all derivatives are immutable, so in-place change should not be a problem (it's the same for `numpy` arrays and `pandas` DataFrame). @tobias_k: The command pattern that you describe is _a_ solution, but it wouldn't allow having say `m2` and `m3` side-by-side and comparing them (for instance) or creating multiple different transformations of the same original list, which would be nice to have...

Answer (score 3):

One simple way of doing this, is to have one single object that stores the list, and then have several referencing objects. The referencing objects will store the transformations and do them on the primary object, when they are needed. This will work exactly as your example, but without ever having more than one copy of the list.

**What you will achieve** (it's the most exciting part, so I'm putting it first)**:**

```
m1 = MyListRef([1, 2, 3, 4])
m2 = m1.remove(2)
m3 = m2.swap(0, 2)
m4 = m2.swap(0, 1) #not a linear series of transformations

print(m1, m2, m3, m4, m1)
#[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 4] [4, 2, 1] [2, 1, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]

print (m1.list is m2.list is m3.list is m4.list)
# True
```

**Code to achieve this:**

Firstly, you need an object to store the only copy of the list. Furthermore, it stores the current history of transformations performed so it can 'reset'  the list to it's original state by doing reverse transformations:

```
class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self, src):
        self.src = src
        self.history = []

    def doTransformations(self, transformations):
        self._resetTransformations()
        self.history = transformations[:]
        for transformation in transformations:
            self.src = transformation.transform(self.src)

    def _resetTransformations(self):
        self.history.reverse()
        for transformation in self.history:
            self.src = transformation.reversetransform(self.src)
```

Secondly, you need the object that you will be interacting with, which will be requesting the transformations to `MyList`. It also stores a list of transformations performed to make non-linear transformations possible (as in the above example):

```
class MyListRef(object):
    ''' OBS: Call 'self.list.doTransformations(self.transformations)' in every
             builtin function you want to use, such as __str__(). '''
    def __init__(self, src, transformations=[]):
        self.list = MyList(src) if type(src) == list else src
        self.transformations = transformations
    def __str__(self):
        self.list.doTransformations(self.transformations)
        return str(self.list.src)

    def _doTransformation(self, transformation):
        transformations = self.transformations + [transformation]
        self.list.doTransformations(transformations)
        return MyListRef(self.list, transformations)

    def remove(self, idx):
        return self._doTransformation(RemoveTransformation(idx))
    def swap(self, idx1, idx2):
        return self._doTransformation(SwapTransformation(idx1, idx2))
```

And not to forget, finally, the transformation objects themselves. Make sure to only change the lists and not copy them. Furthermore, they all need a `reversetransform()` method, which is the opposite of the transformation itself. This is called when `MyList` resets its transformations:

```
class Transformation(object):
    pass

class SwapTransformation(Transformation):
    def __init__(self, idx1, idx2):
        self.idx1 = idx1
        self.idx2 = idx2

    def transform(self, mylist):
        tmp1 = mylist[self.idx1]
        mylist[self.idx1] = mylist[self.idx2]
        mylist[self.idx2] = tmp1
        return mylist

    def reversetransform(self, mylist):
        return self.transform(mylist)

class RemoveTransformation(Transformation):
    def __init__(self, idx):
        self.idx = idx

    def transform(self, mylist):
        self.removed = mylist.pop(self.idx)
        return mylist

    def reversetransform(self, mylist):
        mylist.insert(self.idx, self.removed)
        return mylist
```

*This is enough to make it the above example work as you want it.*

Comment: Interesting approach, but still not what I had in mind. The original list is mutated and the chain of transformations is applied every time you access the list. I'd like to have something that behaves like a 'view' on the original list (for instance skipping an element when the remove transformation was applied during iteration). Apologies if my question didn't describe this sufficiently...

Comment: @orange The approach you're describing would be limited to only access the list through iterating over it. As soon as you want to access individual elements in the transformed list or compare two lists (without iterating), you would have to either make a copy or actually mutate it.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not convinced this is the case. You can overload `__getitem__` the same way you do `__iter__` and mimic the desired behaviour of the transformed list (i.e. in case of swap test if swapped indices are requested and swap them if required).

Comment: @orange True, that might work. I do not believe it would be a simpler or faster solution than this, though. You're welcome to give it a try. Or add a large bounty, so someone else is willing to. ;) I'm however still not sure why you don't like having the original list modified. The result would be almost the same.

Comment: I'll give it a try once I have a little more time and post here. The original list is used elsewhere and part of a larger object whose internal list should not be changed (otherwise other objects would need to be changed also or the object gets corrupted). Nevertheless, I give you a +1 for the nice solution (under other circumstances I'd be happy to accept it).

Comment: @orange Hmm, I see, that makes sense. Maybe I'll give it a try too, another time. We'll see who gets there first.